# Google Load Balancer CDN 502 Errors

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is anybody else using the Google CDN option from the Load Balancer?

In the last hour, it has stopped working for me completely.

I am receiving the message:

502. That’s an error.

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds. That’s all we know.

I have not changed anything in my setup and it just stopped working. I thought maybe my ip address could be blocked, but it's happening from websites that check http headers. I have also switched my ip address and it's still the same.

All 3 of my VM Instances load the file fine. When I goto the file through my CDN ip, it does not work.

Here is all three of my VM Instances:

```
http://104.154.79.149/round.gif
http://104.198.106.79/round.gif
http://104.196.138.170/round.gif
```

Here is the CDN Ip address:

```
http://130.211.31.236/round.gif
```

What is wrong and how can I fix this?

I have created the firewall rule for 130.211.0.0/22 tcp:1-5000  Apply to all targets as suggested in other posts with no success.

Comment: Hi,

I am experiencing a problem again with the Google CDN.

I have checked the incidents reports but do not see anything related to the CDN of Google Compute Engine.

The message I am seeing is

"Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something I believe you are able to resolve as this is also affecting my instances as of around an hour ago. Some of our instances are accessible from some locations as is evidenced by the RPS still ticking over, even if at a reduced rate, and the database activity.

[Edit] I can access my instances by IP (not via the load balancer) but not via load balancer / by domain. I am able to `wget` from other instances and get the correct responses.

Comment: That is good to hear that it's not just me with this issue. I'm sure the Google team is on top of it! Thank you for posting!

Answer (score 1):

Google are having an incident
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/16020

> Google Compute Engine Incident #16020 502s from HTTP(s) Load Balancer
>   Incident began at 2016-10-13 15:00 (all times are US/Pacific).

Although I'd dispute their start time, I believe it began earlier (maybe 14:30 Pacific)