# Google CDN 502 Bad Gateway Errors

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cdn

I am experiencing a problem again with the Google CDN.

I have checked the incidents reports but do not see anything related to the CDN or the Google Compute Engine.

How do I figure out what is going on here? Or if this is already being looked at?

Here is a thread I posted on this before: [Google Load Balancer CDN 502 Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032491/google-load-balancer-cdn-502-errors)

The message I am seeing is "Error: Server Error The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds."

Here are my 3 VM Instances

```
 http://104.154.79.149/round.gif
 http://104.198.106.79/round.gif
 http://104.196.138.170/round.gif
```

And here is the CDN Ip address

```
http://130.211.31.236/round.gif
```

The VM Instances load fine but there is a problem with the CDN.

When I click through to the Cloud CDN, go into my instance and look in the monitoring for HTTP. It says

```
 cdn-west-1-group us-west1-a  0 of 1 instance healthy

 cdn-central-1-group us-central1-b 0 of 1 instance healthy

 cdn-east-1-group us-east1-b 0 of 1 instance healthy
```

Here are my firewall rules for the CDN

```
 IP ranges  
 130.211.0.0/22
 35.191.0.0/16
 209.85.204.0/22
 209.85.152.0/22
```

With allowed ports 1-5000

Here is the default-allow-internal rule

```
 10.128.0.0/9

 tcp:0-65535 udp:0-65535 icmp
```

Can anybody please help? I did not change anything recently and it just stopped working overnight.

Comment: This appears to be something with the CDN being unable to access the VM instances. The VM Instances can still be accessed through the public but not through the CDN.

I've updated the post with all of my firewall rules.

Comment: I have found the problem!

Some how all 3 of my instances have failed with mysql at the same time?

I've restarted mysql on all of the box's and everything is running fine again.

So weird!!!